# Conditional JOIN issue, if one field is empty select other value to join with

Tags: php, mysql, join, left-join

I have an issue. I want to join a table "companies" on a "users" table. The thing is, an user can either be an author/creator of a company, or be a member.

This means in case one the field users.company is empty, but the field companies.authorID is filled with the user id or
Second case, users.company is filled with the company id and companies.authorID is empty.

How can I join the companies table to the users table then?

Should be sth like

```
LEFT JOIN companies ON companies.id = users.company AND IF users.company = '0' THEN ON companies.authorID = users.id
```

Is there any way to achieve what I want within the join clause?

Thanks a lot!

Current state with complete clause (crashes the query)

```
SELECT 
count(users.id),
companies.city AS selectVariable
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN companies ON companies.id = users.company OR (users.company = '0' AND companies.authorID = users.id)
WHERE users.email <> '' AND users.deleted = '0'
GROUP BY companies.city
ORDER BY count(users.id) DESC
LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
```

This solution is working but def. not as clean as I would like it to be...

```
SELECT 
count(users.id),
    (
    CASE 
        WHEN users.company = '0' THEN c2.city
        WHEN users.company > '0' THEN c.city
        ELSE NULL
    END) AS selectVariable
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN companies c ON c.id = users.company
LEFT JOIN companies c2 ON c2.authorID = users.id
WHERE users.email <> '' AND users.deleted = '0'
GROUP BY selectVariable
ORDER BY count(users.id) DESC
LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
```

Comment: Do you want to count users that are not associated with a company at all? Can a user be a member as well as a creator/owner (doesn't have to be the same company).

Comment: It's not just a simple order of operations issue? You only have brackets around the second half of the OR statement. What happens if you bracket the first half too?  JOIN Table ON (condition1) OR (condition2)

Comment: @MaxxaM hey, I will try the bracket thing now. I want to get a city to each user. but the city is part of the company.

Comment: Solved it now, but not a perfekt solution...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `or` criteria in the `join`:

```
LEFT JOIN companies c ON c.id = u.company 
           OR (u.company = '0' AND c.authorID = u.id)
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick reply. One issue, im using a count(users.id) in the select clause and once I use the or in the join clause the performance is gone... I just posted the whole query in the main post now

Comment: its crashing the db, taking like forever...
users has 60k entries and companies 15k

Comment: @jQuery Maybe you are fetching multiple rows from the users table for each companies data.. or you can try the `JOIN` or `INNER JOIN`.